# Pergunta simples de PHP , preciso de uma estrutura, caso o curso tenha nome , não pode excluir!

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Fala pessoal beleza então o seguinte , em excluir curso deve ser respeitar a ideia que , onde não podem ter nome vinculados com aquele curso, ou seja, se tiver nome que tenha aquele curso, não poderá ser excluído,como montaria a estrutura , tentei algumas , mais ta complicado, sou iniciante.
abaixo como esta montado curso excluir até o momento!

```
<?php

include "../includes/conexao.php";

   $id = $_GET['id'];


   $sql = "DELETE  FROM curso where id = $id";


   $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);


if($query){
    header("location: curso.php?mensagem=sucesso");
}else{
    header("location: curso_excluir.php?mensagem=erro");
}

?>
```

Comment: Evite imagem, edite sua pergunta e cole nela seu código

Comment: "onde não podem ter nome vinculados com aquele curso" ... Nao entendi direito. O nome que vc se refere é um campo da tabela curso?

Comment: Isso, é como se ao inserir o curso da ''tabela curso'' em usuario, o mesmo não pode ser excluído na tabela curso , pois o mesmo esta cadastrado um usuario .

Comment: @ManchadoManoel posta a tabela usuário do curso

Answer (score -1):

Deixe-me ver se entendi. Você tem 2 tabelas:
Cursos
Participantes Cursos

Você quer que o curso só possa ser excluído se não houver nenhum participante para o curso em questão?

Se for isso, você tem 2 maneiras de fazê-lo:
1 - Integridade Referencial no Banco de Dados.
2 - Via Código PHP

Como você se diz iniciante, vou te dar a sugestão via código que eu acho de mais simples entendimento, porém, não acho que seja a mais adequada.

Você deverá fazer uma consulta na tabela de participantes e ver se há ou não participantes cadastrados.
Ex:

```
$consulta_participantes = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT blablabla FROM participantes_cursos WHERE id_curso = '$idcurso'");

$qtd_participantes = mysqli_num_rows($consulta_participantes);
```

Com a quantidade de participantes em mãos, através da variável $qtd_participantes, faça um IF para ver para onde será encaminhado.

Ex:

```
if($qtd_participantes == "0"){
    header("location: exclui_curso.php?id=$idcurso");
} else {
    header("location: lista_cursos.php?mensagem=Não foi possível excluir o curso pois já há participantes inscritos");
};
```

Foi um exemplo bem simplista mas que irá te ajudar a entender e resolver seu problema.

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas fiz o que disse, e esta dando erro, será que não esta apontando corretamente as tabelas.

Comment: Mostre o código completo e a estrutura das tabelas, ai fica mais fácil de verificar.

Comment: ok!vou deixar em cima,